# Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'iter'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, gensim, word2vec, epoch

```
# train word vectors
w2v_model.train(sentences, total_examples=w2v_model.corpus_count, epochs=w2v_model.iter)
```

i got this error

```
AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'iter'
```

Could you give me some hints to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You've likely copied code from an example which is at the very least several years outdated (& might have worse problems). So, even when you get past this error, there may be others. You may want to seek a better/more-recent template.

That said, it may be enough to resolve this one particular error to change your code that references `w2v_model.iter` (an attribute not present in recent Gensim `Word2Vec` code) to say `w2v_model.epochs` instead.

(Still: any code with this problem likely has others as well.)